# Capybara/Poltergeist: CSS Attribute Selector raising syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara 2.3 with Poltergeist (on Rails), and I've encountered a problem when calling 'has_selector' with a CSS selector which includes attribute value.
For Example:

```
page.has_selector? "select#select_id option[value!='1']"
```

results in the following error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::InvalidSelector: The browser raised a syntax error while trying to evaluate css selector "select#select_id option[value!='1']"
```

Since I'm using the '!=' operator, I can't use the 'args' parameter of 'has_selector?' (or can I?)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`!=` is not a valid CSS attribute comparator (at least in chrome). You might want to try

```
page.has_selector? "select#select_id option:not([value='1'])"
```

You can achieve the same with the `:not` pseudo-class.

Comment: Interesting -- PhantomJS doesn't report != as an error, even with spaces around it.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Try this [script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/94351cd8644251e9b878). Do you see the error? I do and I'm on Win7 with phantomjs 1.9.7-9.

Comment: Yes I do! Seems like something in Capybara or poltergeist implements or eats `!=`. Brief investigation reveals that Capybara does a lot of processing of the selector, so perhaps that's why.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth: It's not a valid CSS selector, period. If it's being accepted then the respective implementation is probably just doing its own thing.

Comment: Also, `:not()` is not a pseudo-element, but a pseudo-class.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, I changed it. I don't know what happened there.